# Update row based on a group measure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
[UNIT] [PRICE] [QUANTITY] [REVENUE]     [PERCENTAGE]
A      $10     25         $250           25%
B      $5      30         $150           15%
C      $20     30         $600           60%
Total Revenue             $1,000             100%
```

I'm trying to create a query to calculate the [PERCENTAGE] column, here is what I used:

```
UPDATE Table
SET [PERCENTAGE] = (PRICE*QUANTITY)/(sum(PRICE*QUANTITY)
```

Here is the error message:

An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Any Suggestion?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE
    t1 target
    CROSS JOIN t1 src
SET
    target.PERCENTAGE = target.PRICE * target.QUANTITY / 
(SELECT SUM(src.PRICE * src.QUANTITY))
```

Comment: Since there is only one table here, would CROSS JOIN still be needed?

Comment: @user2101399 I believe so; I don't think that MySQL will let you specify the same table that you select from for updating

Comment: Are you saying in your example 'target' and 'src' refer to the same table?

Comment: @user2101399 they refer to the same table in the schema, yes

Comment: @user2101399 can you be more specific?  "it doesn't work" can mean about 50 different things

Comment: UPDATE TMP_SAMPLE_CAL

SET
    PERCENTAGE = PRICE * QUANTITY / 
(SELECT SUM(TMP_SAMPLE_CAL.PRICE * TMP_SAMPLE_CAL.QUANTITY))
from     TMP_SAMPLE_CAL 
    CROSS JOIN TMP_SAMPLE_CAL

Comment: Error Message: The objects "TMP_SAMPLE_CAL" and "TMP_SAMPLE_CAL" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: @user2101399 that's different than what I told you to do though?  Why would you expect it to work?

Comment: src is not recognized as a build in reference by SQL Server, is there another name for it? otherwise I would't be able to use it.

Comment: The table and column names are included in the comment above in capital letters, would you be able re-write the query using the correct names? I appreciate it.

Comment: I might have replaced the wrong syntax in your original post with what I have, so if you could re-write the query using the names provided above it would help a lot, thanks.

Comment: Hi I figured it out, I revised my query to:

SET [PERCENTAGE] = (PRICE*QUANTITY)/(sum(PRICE*QUANTITY)from MyTable)

in the first one 'from MyTable' is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this with window functions and a `with` clause:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             sum(price*quantity) over () as total
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set percentage = price*quantity / total;
```